# How to open all mp3 files using windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

If I have the following directory:

```
C:\Users\mkt\Desktop\Music\Tool\Lateralus
```

and want to open all files contained in the folder using cmd prompt. how could I do that?

I know that the following line will open one of them:

```
cd C:\Users\mkt\Desktop\Music\Tool\Lateralus\"01 - The Grudge.mp3"
```

But what about multiple files?

I am a noob at DOS and I really shouldn't be, but without practice you will never get better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering, why it is opening your mp3 file with the cd command.

The cd command is used to switch directories, so this is something new for me.
I am a MAC OS user, so I could not test it, but if your given example worked, I think this should work too:

```
cd C:\Users\mkt\Desktop\Music\Tool\Lateralus\*.mp3
```

With the "*.mp3" you say, every mp3 file.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, im using this approach to practice and couldnt find a solution to this problem anywhere conveniently... I want to be able to write batch files from scratch for future use. Unfortunately this would not work for me but thank you for the response

Comment: I Would recommend the "start" command. For Example: 
start c:\music\"my song.mp3" if it does not work wit the "*" you could iterate over the folder containing your mp3 files and open them stem by step. Like this you can iterate over files only in a directory: "for %f in (.\*) do @echo %f"

Comment: This is what I found on the net for only mp3 files "for %i in (*.mp3) do echo %i" hope this helps

Comment: I tried the start command but it unfortunately only opens one file at a time as opposed to multiple as trying the *.mp3 command returns an error where it cannot find the file.